# How to use Dropbox Datastore API in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, dropbox-api, datastore

I've developed an HTML5 app using Symfony2 with my own data model (using Doctrine2). Right now, I want to integrate my app with others apps (for iOS and Android), sharing and syncronizing the same data model, using [Dropbox Datastore API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore).

The apps for iOS and Android (developed by others) mentioned above are working perfectly with Dropbox Datastore API.

I was reading the official documentation and I've seen that exists an SDK for JS but I don't know if this SDK is valid for working with Symfony2 because I think the best way to call to the data model is in the controllers (server side, via PHP) and not in views (client side, via JS).

Maybe exists a bundle for this functionality (I haven't found anything about it) or a good way for work with this API in PHP or, maybe, it's possible in JavaScript (recalling the app has been developed in Symfony).

Someone has tried that? What is the best way to work with that API and how I can do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Searching on Packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=Dropbox) is always a good starting point! Looks like there's already several packages made, and more generic OAuth packages if you want something more basic,

Comment: I did it but there are not bundles related with [Dropbox Datastore](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore)